# Bootstrap Datetimepicker daysOfWeekDisabled option doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

So I have one input with date+time value (getting values from DB) and I am using jQuery Datetime picker to change date/time.

Here is my input

```
<div class="input-group form-group td-350">
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" name="new_preffered_date" class="form-control datetimepickers" value="<?= $item->customer_preferred_date->i18nFormat('dd.MM.YYYY HH:mm', 'Europe/Vienna') ?>"/>
    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon-calendar glyphicon"></span></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is my Datetimepicker configuration:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendors/bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.datetimepickers').each(function () {
      $(this).datetimepicker({
        daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
        format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',
        locale: 'de',
        minDate: new Date(),
      });
    });
</script>
```

With this configuration, Datetimepicker take as default value always date time from now. If I delete `daysOfWeekDisabled` option than I can see real date/time from database in input.

Info: My date from database is not weekend and is newer as now().

So my question is, how can I use DateTime picker with `daysOfWeekDisabled` option and as default value show date from database?

Documentation of Datetime picker is http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#daysofweekdisabled

Comment: Are you sure that a date from your database has the `'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'` format? Did you try to remove `minDate` field? By the way,  the last comma is excess.

Comment: Yes, I am converting that day, and if I remove daysOfWeekDisabled option then everything is find, also I have tried to remove other options (one by one) and result is same. Its really wierd...

Comment: Try to set [`useCurrent`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent) to false. Has it helped?

Comment: @Alexander it really helps, thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the [`useCurrent`](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#usecurrent) property to `false`.  It will set the picker to the selected date/time instead of current.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you do not need to use **each loop** you can direct use like this

```
  $(".datetimepickers").datetimepicker({
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
    format: 'DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm',
    locale: 'de',
    defaultDate: "11/1/2013",//pass your database date
    minDate: new Date(),
  });
```

Comment: I have already try this, and using defaultDate: today.getDate()+2 but default date is always now() if I use daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],